# Adding Items to TreeView doesn't show them

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, treeview

this is my scenario:
I'm working on this TreeView:

```
<s:SurfaceWindow .... >
    <Grid>
    .....
        <TreeView Name="DriveTree" Margin="5" Height="300" Width="300" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <s:SurfaceButton Click="CloseApplication">Chiudi  applicazione</s:SurfaceButton>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</s:SurfaceWindow>
```

I have a timer that each X seconds control for new external plugged in drives and on elapsed it calls this function:

```
public void GetRemovableDrives()
{ 
    //drives variable is a list of driveInfo where I save active drives

    DriveInfo[] dInfos = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    List<int> dInfosToRemove = new List<int>();

    foreach (DriveInfo si in dInfos)
        if (drives.Find(x => x.Name == si.Name) == null && si.IsReady && MtUtilities.IsProjectOnExternalDisk(si.Name))
        {    
            drives.Add(si);
            DriveTree.Items.Add(this.GetItem(si));
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < drives.Count(); i++)
        if (!dInfos.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(drives[i].Name))
            dInfosToRemove.Add(i);

    foreach (int d in dInfosToRemove)
    {
        drives.RemoveAt(d);
        DriveTree.Items.RemoveAt(d + 2);
    }
}
```

When I call for the first time (in Window constructor) it works like a charm, but when is called by timer it removes or adds items in DriveTree (if I pause debugging I can see that the element is added/removed in items list by an immediate window) but the visibile treeView in application isn't updated, it doesn't show me the new items, like the UI doesn't get them..
Any ideas?

Comment: I can't tell if you're using MVVM or not.  Is `DriveTree` the `x:Name` of your `TreeView`?  I would assume so.  In any case, this issue would not occur if you used MVVM/data binding properly.  I would shoot for no code-behind (xaml.cs) if I were you.  The fact that you're adding to a collection, then removing from the same collection, and trying to keep two collections have the same elements is worrisome.  This is a perfect opportunity for data binding; you would only need to maintain one collection then.

Comment: Is the item actually not being remove or is it not appearing to be removed? Try breaking before and step across to see if the element in the local watch is indeed removed. If it is it's probably an issue of the UI being updated. If this is the case try `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { drives.RemoveAt(d); DriveTree.Items.RemoveAt(d + 2);}));` instead or implement the [OnPropertyChanced Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onpropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) But if possible try and follow @NETscape 's suggestion.

Comment: @CalebB, your hint works perfectly, thank you

Comment: Sure thing. I would encourage you to work on developing an MVVM model, or similar concept for your apps, as @NETscape mention, in the future though. It helps make yours app much more flexible and enterprise worthy.

Comment: @NETscape  I will develop an MVVM model as soon as possible and I will give you a feedback, thank you